# Tuberculosis test requirement for Netherlands residence permit

Tags: health, residency

As per https://ind.nl/en/Pages/General_conditions.aspx someone applying for a residence permit has to go through a tuberculosis test unless exempt by certain conditions mentioned in the following list.

Two questions about this:

1. What happens if the tuberculosis test turns out to be positive? Is the residence permit denied then or is it put on hold?
2. What happens if the applicant had tuberculosis in the past but no longer has tuberculosis?

Answer (score 4):

1. Nothing with respect to the residence permit.

Note that the condition says

> After having arrived in the Netherlands, you will undergo a medical test for tuberculosis (TB).

not that you must be TB-free.

This is confirmed by the international help organization in the Hague:

> It is important to know that even if the test shows that you have TB, this will not have any consequences for you residence permit. The GGD will only notify the IND of you taking the test, not the results of the test.
> https://www.thehagueinternationalcentre.nl/relocating/formalities/tuberculosis-check.

You will also see that the result is not included in the form to be filled and signed by the physician:
https://ind.nl/en/Forms/7604.pdf.

Of course, the doctor will prescribe appropriate treatment. Tuberculosis is a notifiable infectious disease in the Netherlands (and most countries in the world). If you refuse to undergo treatments, you may suffer consequences under public health laws and your residence permit may be affected then.

2. There is no consequence for residence permit whatever the history is but as noted above refusal of treatment in case of positive result may have further consequences. In any case, any history of TB would still be a useful information to provide to the doctor.

Comment: I agree that  #2 should be changed as suggested by @DavidSupportsMonica. A **refusal to be treated** would be reported and have consequences.